# Total crash under IE7 - FIX

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, joomla, internet-explorer-7

I using Joomla with VirtueMart for e-commerce webpage. Also i install plugin to VirtueMart for product sliding. The gallery work fine but under IE7 all page just block don't have any link that is clickable,just all links at the page goes unclickable. [Here is the site](http://shoesnbags.de/index.php/herbst-winter-2012-2013/paolo-bocelli-damenschuhe-keilabsatz-3m-12427-detail) 
I don't know what to search to fix this problem. Any suggestions how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to gradualy disable js files to check if it's a JavaScript problem.
- Do the same with CSS files.